# How to send ASCII character from Microcontroller using Assembly

Tags: assembly, avr

I try to send ASCII character to my personal computer via serial from my AVR ATMEGA8535 microcontroller.
If I want to send an "A" character i use this code :

```
MOV TMOD,#20H        ;timer1,mode 2(auto reload)
MOV TH1,#-6          ;4800 baud rate
MOV SCON,#50H        ;8-bit, 1 stop, REN enabled
SETB TR1             ;start timer 1
AGAIN: MOV SBUF,#”A” ;letter “A” to transfer
HERE: JNB TI,HERE    ;wait for the last bit
CLR TI               ;clear TI for next char
SJMP AGAIN           ;keep sending A
```

but how to send characters that generated from an ADC ?

Comment: There's probably lots of example code available on the internet for reading data from the ADC on that microcontroller. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: an ADC does not generate characters. Look at your datasheet how to setup ADC and how to setup UART. and write some ftoa routine or even better: use C and some libraries to save development time and create maintainable programms

Comment: – 8K Bytes of In-System Self-Programmable Flash
...
– 512 Bytes Internal SRAM
What kind of libraries you had in mind?   Is this of any help (yes it's C): http://pastebin.com/g0szBfXe